# Aggregate log table records to avoid redundancy

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table for product change tracking that looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ProductHistory (
  ProductId INT NOT NULL,
  Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Price MONEY NOT NULL,
  StartDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
  EndDate DATETIME NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO ProductHistory VALUES
(1, 'Phone',       100, '2020-11-20 00:00', '2020-11-20 01:00'), /* initial */
(1, 'Phone',       100, '2020-11-20 01:01', '2020-11-20 02:00'), /* no change */
(1, 'Phone',       200, '2020-11-20 02:01', '2020-11-20 03:00'), /* no change, current */

(2, 'Apple',          5, '2020-11-20 00:00', '2020-11-20 01:00'), /* initial */
(2, 'Apple',         10, '2020-11-20 01:01', '2020-11-20 02:00'), /* changed */
(2, 'Pineapple',     10, '2020-11-20 02:01', '2020-11-20 03:00'), /* no change, current */

(3, 'Orange juice', 100, '2020-11-21 00:00', '2020-11-21 01:00'), /* initial */
(3, 'Orange juice', 100, '2020-11-21 01:01', '2020-11-21 02:00'), /* no change */
(3, 'Orange juice', 100, '2020-11-21 02:01', '2020-11-21 03:00')  /* no change, current */
```

I was hoping to come up with a query to get the results below. Notice that the records without actual changes are supposed to be merged together so that there is no redudancy.

```
  ProductId       Name       Price                StartDate                               EndDate                 
 ----------- -------------- ------- -------------------------------------- -------------------------------------- 
          1   Phone            100   2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 (first row)    2020-11-20 02:00:00.000 (second row)  
          1   Phone            200   2020-11-20 02:01:00.000 (third row)    2020-11-20 03:00:00.000 (third row)   

          2   Apple              5   2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 (first row)    2020-11-20 01:00:00.000 (first row)   
          2   Apple             10   2020-11-20 01:01:00.000 (second row)   2020-11-20 02:00:00.000 (second row)  
          2   Pineapple         10   2020-11-20 02:01:00.000 (third row)    2020-11-20 03:00:00.000 (third row)   

          3   Orange juice     100   2020-11-21 00:00:00.000 (first row)    2020-11-20 03:00:00.000 (third row)
```

The closest I got to was the following:

```sql
; WITH history AS (
    SELECT
        ProductId,
        Name,
        Price,
        StartDate,
        EndDate
    FROM (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY StartDate DESC) 'RowNumber',
            *
        FROM ProductHistory
    ) history
    WHERE history.RowNumber = 1 -- select newest row per ProductId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        previous.ProductId,
        previous.Name,
        previous.Price,
        previous.StartDate,
        EndDate
    FROM (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY previous.ProductId ORDER BY previous.StartDate DESC) 'RowNumber',
            previous.*
        FROM history [current]
        INNER JOIN ProductHistory previous
            ON previous.ProductId = [current].ProductId
            AND previous.StartDate < [current].StartDate
            AND (
                previous.Name <> [current].Name
                OR previous.Price <> [current].Price
            )   
    ) previous
    WHERE previous.RowNumber = 1 -- select previous row of each ProductId, recursively
)

SELECT *
FROM history
ORDER BY
    ProductId,
    StartDate
```

```
  ProductId       Name       Price           StartDate                  EndDate          
 ----------- -------------- -------- ------------------------- ------------------------- 
          1   Phone          100,00   2020-11-20 01:01:00.000   2020-11-20 02:00:00.000  
          1   Phone          200,00   2020-11-20 02:01:00.000   2020-11-20 03:00:00.000  

          2   Apple            5,00   2020-11-20 00:00:00.000   2020-11-20 01:00:00.000  
          2   Apple           10,00   2020-11-20 01:01:00.000   2020-11-20 02:00:00.000  
          2   Pineapple       10,00   2020-11-20 02:01:00.000   2020-11-20 03:00:00.000  

          3   Orange juice   100,00   2020-11-21 02:01:00.000   2020-11-21 03:00:00.000
```

While the `Name` and `Price` column values are right, I'm not sure how to aggregate the `StartDate` and `EndDate` columns to get what I need. All code is available in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b33468b1ce193cd9b80e9076c531b949), if it's of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  Probably the simplest method is the difference of row numbers:

```
select productid, name, price, min(startdate), max(enddate)
from (select ph.*,
             row_number() over (partition by productid order by startdate) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by productid, name, price order by startdate) as seqnum_2
      from producthistory
     ) ph
group by productid, name, price, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

This assumes that there are no gaps in the time frames -- which seems reasonable with this data model.

Why does this work?  That is a little hard to explain.  But if you look at the results of the subquery, you will see how the difference between the two row numbers is constant for adjacent rows where `name` and `price` are the same.

Comment: You're right, I have no idea why this works! The hardest part about this problem was not knowing what it's called, so now I guess I have a bit of studying to do. Thanks a lot for pushing me in the right direction. :) / Though would you mind going a bit more in detail of when your solution would *not* work? What would a gap look like in my scenario? Something like 20200501, 20200502, 20200504? Does it really matter even if we're using ORDER BY StartDate?

Comment: @VítorMartins . . . It depends on how you want to handle a gap.  This method ignores the gap.  However, you might want to break a gap into different rows.